# Powershell Only Copy Matching Files from Directory

Tags: powershell

I want to copy files from one Sourcediretcory to a targetDirectory based off of a referenceDirectory.

The SourceDirectory has ~all files. I only want a subset of these files ( note some are in subdirectories ).

I want to copy some of these files from the C:\SourceDirectory\ to a C:\TargetDirectory but I only want to copy the files which appear in my C:\ReferenceDirectory.

I'm not sure how I can do this in Powershell, because I will have separate directory Prefixes.

I did fin some code already but i don't think works for the different directory names. It would be really great if it didn't have to generate a list of Target files as an intermediate step.

step1
CMD `dir * /s/b > ReferenceFiles.txt`

step2
POWERSHELL `cat ReferenceFiles.txt  | ForEach {cp $_ <destination TargetDirectory>}`

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are really not giving all the needed info to give you a definitive answer.

As, what does this mean...

> because I will have separate directory Prefixes.

... as you are not showing it.

You are specifically asking for the difference from Reference vs Source, thus you have to have a step for that. You can do that outside of a loop.

For the simple case...

```
Clear-Host
# Show all files from the copy source
($fsoSource = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path 'D:\temp\Source')

# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\temp\Source


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        29-Dec-19     21:50             69 5 Free Software You'll Wish You Knew Earlier! 2019 - YouTube.url
-a----        10-Jan-20     17:59              0 awél.txt
-a----        25-Jan-20     15:43            176 book1.csv
-a----        01-Feb-20     00:22             66 FileList.txt
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:01             39 hello.bat
-a----        04-Jan-20     01:43             44 hello.ps1
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest - Copy.txt
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest.txt
-a----        19-Jan-20     14:49            230 mytest.zip
-a----        01-Jan-20    ...
#>

# Show files to copy from reference target
($fsoReference = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path 'D:\temp\Reference' -Recurse)

# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\temp\Reference


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        10-Jan-20     17:59              0 awél.txt
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:01             39 hello.bat
-a----        04-Jan-20     01:43             44 hello.ps1
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest - Copy.txt
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest.txt
#>

$fsoSource | 
ForEach{
    If ($PSItem.Name -in $fsoReference.Name)
    {Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination 'D:\Temp\Target' -WhatIf} 
}

# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\temp\Source\awél.txt Destination: D:\Temp\Target\awél.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\temp\Source\hello.bat Destination: D:\Temp\Target\hello.bat".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\temp\Source\hello.ps1 Destination: D:\Temp\Target\hello.ps1".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\temp\Source\mytest - Copy.txt Destination: D:\Temp\Target\mytest - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\temp\Source\mytest.txt Destination: D:\Temp\Target\mytest.txt".
#>
```

If you have specific directories, then you have to specify those in kind.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to copy only files from the source directory if a matching file exists in the reference directory.

To do that, this should work:

```
$sourceDir      = 'C:\SourceDirectory'
$destinationDir = 'C:\TargetDirectory'
$referenceDir   = 'C:\ReferenceDirectory'

# create the destination directory if it does not exist, otherwise
# create an array of files already contained in that directory
# in order to prevent overwriting them
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationDir -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $destinationDir -ItemType Directory
    $destFiles = @()
}
else {
    $destFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationDir -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique
}

# get a list of file names that are present in C:\ReferenceDirectory
$refFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $referenceDir -File -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique

# next, go through the files in the source directory and copy the files that are listed
# in array $refFiles, but NOT in array $destFiles to the target directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $refFiles -contains $_.Name -and $destFiles -notcontains $_.Name } | 
    Copy-Item -Destination $destinationDir
```